# can I create an SSRS group without adding the group to the box itself and without using Active Directory?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I want to know if it is possible to create a group "internal" to SSRS without having to add the group to the ReportServer box itself.

I do not have permissions to the box to create groups and/or add users to existing groups.  I know that this is a way (the only way?) to have groups that can be assigned permissions in the SSRS interface.

I do have all the permissions I need within the SSRS interface.  I have the System Administrator System Role on the ReportServer instance, as well as full sysadmin rights to the ReportServer database.

I am trying to simplify our security structure and it would be peachy if I could create a group, assign users to that group, and then permissions to the group.  But all I seem to be able to do is assign permissions to the groups set up on the box.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Active Directory groups are not an option for me.  :(

Comment: is your report server on a domain?

Comment: yes, the report server is on a domain.

Comment: Sorry. I was deleting that comment - I'm not 100% sure I'm following you given the amount of time "Report Server" is used. Are you asking if you can create a group on the SSRS implementation that has permissions to a report/set of reports without having to assign them permission on the actual server itself MYREPORTSERVER.DOMAIN.EXT ?

Comment: I just edited my post to clarify my use of ReportServer (I hope).  To answer your question in the coment - yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: My first inclination would be to have AD groups set up and then you can divvy up permissions through the SSRS interface http://MYREPORTSERVER/Reports/Pages/Settings.aspx?SelectedSubTabId=SecurityLinkID

Comment: I don't think that's an option for me either - though I am checking with the powers that be...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3883/discussion-between-jhfb-and-swasheck)

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of courses of action for you:

- If you're friendly with your Windows Admin, I'd thoughtfully think out some AD Groups and then present them to the admin and ask them to be created (in whatever workflow you have).
- From there you can assign permissions on the individual folders by these groups. Click on the folder, then click on Properties.

[image]

- On the left you will see "Security," click that. Then click "Edit
  Item Security." You may get a dialog that tells you that the item
  currently inherits from parent. You may need to wait for a bit before
  this completes, but be patient.

[image]

- If successful you will have checkboxes next to the principles already
  with access. From here choose "New Role Assignment"

[image]

- Now you can add your AD Group in the next page and assign it the permissions necessary. Try with DOMAIN\GroupName

[image]

Obviously this will be much easier if you have AD groups, but if you can't get that, then you can do this with individual domain users. That would be a management nightmare?

Comment: Thanks for all the detail, @swasheck.  Problem is, I don't have access to AD groups - and I can't get friendly with my Windows Admin.  Any other options?  I'm looking at 150+ users that could be divided into 50 or so groups to ease the pain.  I miss other BI tools right now... :(

Comment: Wow, that's a real shame. 150+ users is a management nightmare to do individually. I am thinking of a hacky workaround, but it's not really the right way. I'd probably push the political system at your pace of employment to come to a workable solution for everyone. Otherwise it's create a linked server to AD using ADSI to query AD and get SIDs for users. Then you could put those into `ReportServer.dbo.Users` and then map the users to `Roles` and then `PolicyUserRole` using items in `Catalog`. There are probably a few more that I'm missing.